# Contents in Kubernetes pod gets empty when persistent volume is mounted

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cloud, yaml

### persistent volume claim and persistent volume yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/datatypo"


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  volumeName: my-volume
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

### Deployment yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: typo3
  labels:
    app: typo3
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - nodePort: 31021
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: typo3
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: typo3
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: typo3
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: typo3
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - typo3
      containers:
      - image: image:typo3
        name: typo3
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
         - name: my-volume
           mountPath: /var/www/html/
      volumes:
           - name: my-volume
             persistentVolumeClaim:
                 claimName: my-claim
```

Note: if the persistent volume is not added, then contents were showing inside the pod (in `var/www/html`). But after adding the persistent volume then it's not showing any contents inside the same folder and the external mount path `/mnt/datatypo`.

Comment: do you have content in `/mnt/datatypo` on the host itself? It won't get copied from your container `/var/www/html/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour: when persistent volume is mounted, it overwrites content of the folder which is specified in `mountPath`.

Therefore you have two options:

- have content of that directory presented on your host machine already
- mount `hostPath` into another directory in container and then copy content to the final destination folder. (Can be achieved with [command in container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/))

Also you can mount a single file, there are different options of `hostPath types`. Please get familiar with [hostPath types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath).

**Note!** Using `hostPath` mount can be used only for testing some features locally, it's very insecure approach in production systems:

> Warning: HostPath volumes present many security risks, and it is a
> best practice to avoid the use of HostPaths when possible. When a
> HostPath volume must be used, it should be scoped to only the required
> file or directory, and mounted as ReadOnly

[Volumes - hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath).